# Движение по странице с помощью курсора

Tags: reactjs, svg, drag-n-drop, draggable

Наверное немного туплю и ответ прост, но может кто научит и расскажет.

Есть страница с родовым деревом. Нужно реализовать перемещение по странице с помощью курсора (как например в фигме или других редакторах (рука))

Пишу на react, и если есть какой простой способ, пожалуйста отпишитесь

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону @pronestor/react-zoom-pan-pinch